# How to measure ping latency in flash/red5 mediaserver

Tags: flash, red5, latency, ping

Only thing I found is QoS statistic in NetConnection.info, but it does not contain any kind of latency values.

In red5 API "IConnection.getLastPingTime()" exists, is it accessible over standard Flex API or I need to poll it by RMI calls?

Answer (score 0):

Jake Hilton wrote a port testing application (source available) which may help you or set you in the right direction. 
http://www.jakehilton.com/?q=node/43

As far as the IConnection methods we offer on the server side, a lot of these must be exposed if you want to call them directly from Flash/Flex application.